# Convert object to HTTP Request Parameters (key/value pairs)

Tags: java, rest, serialization, marshalling

Assume I have an object model like:

```
class B {
    string msg;
}

class A {
    string name;
    int[] nums;
    B obj;
}
```

when `A` instance serialized to JSON it would look like:

```
{"name": "John", "nums": [1,2,3], "obj": {"msg" : "foo" }}
```

so I am looking for a converter which would serialize this object to standard HTTP POST/PUT form data or GET query string parameters e.g. see the following request body, **I need to get the following**:

```
name=John&nums[0]=1&nums[1]=2&nums[2]=3&obj.msg=foo
```

I could not find any libraries doing this procedure (converting object to key-value map, recursively and supporting collections).

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jacksonmapper and provide your custom mapper implementation if the default conversion doesn't suit you. It integrates well with Spring too if you're using Spring in your project .

Comment: I'm surprised this is not ready off-the-shelf, I'll look a bit more before writing my own.

Answer (score -1):

google-gson should help you :
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

User guide : https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Classes-

And then you could use this library to convert JSON to GET url : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: fjammes, I don't want to use JSON. I want to marshal my object to key value pairs. Please read question carefully.